# trying to merge two functions into one

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am working with an existing piece of code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/HggGjgvTzggHPE6KYuOz?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>



  <style>
  .states {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
    }

    .county:hover {
      fill: red !important;
    }
    /*

 .tooltiptext {

    visibility: hidden;

    width: 120px;

    background-color: #555;

    color: #fff;

    text-align: center;

    padding: 5px 0;

    border-radius: 6px;



    position: absolute;

    z-index: 1;

    bottom: 125%;

    left: 50%;

    margin-left: -60px;



      opacity: 0;

    transition: opacity 1s;

}

 .tooltiptext::after {

    content: "";

    position: absolute;

    top: 100%;

    left: 50%;

    margin-left: -5px;

    border-width: 5px;

    border-style: solid;

    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;

}



svg:hover .tooltiptext {

    visibility: visible;

    opacity: 1;

}

*/

    svg:hover {
      background: black;
    }
  }
  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="float:left,width:40%" id="click"></div>

  <!-- For Dropdown menu -->

  <select onchange="Dropdown(this.value)">

    <option>Unemployeement</option>

    <option>New File</option>

  </select>

  <script>
    $("div").click(function() {

      alert("here");

    });

    var width = 960,

      height = 500;



    var color = d3.scale.threshold()

    .domain([0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10])

    .range(["#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f"]);



    var path = d3.geo.path();



    var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")

    .attr("width", width)

    .attr("height", height);



    queue()

    .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")

    .defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv")

    .await(ready);



    function ready(error, us, unemployment) {

      if (error) throw error;



      var rateById = {};



      unemployment.forEach(function(d) {
        rateById[d.id] = +d.rate;
      });



      svg.append("g")

      .attr("class", "counties")

      .selectAll("path")

      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)

      .enter().append("path")

      .attr("d", path)

      .attr("class", "county")

      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(rateById[d.id]);

      });

      svg.append("path")

      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
        return a.id !== b.id;
      }))

      .attr("class", "states")

      .attr("d", path);

      var object = svg.append("foreignobject");

      var div = object.append("div");

      var tooltip = d3.select("div").append("span")

      .attr("class", "ccc")

      .style("z-index", "10")

      .style("visibility", "hidden")

      .style("position", "absolute")

      .style("text-align", "center")

      .style("width", "60px")

      .style("height", "28px")

      .style("padding", "2px")

      .style("font", "12px sans-serif")

      .style("background", "lightsteelblue")

      .style("border", "0px")

      .style("border-radius", "8px")

      .style("pointer-events", "none")

      .text("here");



      d3.select("div")

      .on("mouseover", function() {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      })

      .on("mousemove", function() {
        return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
      })

      .on("mouseout", function() {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      });

      $("span").click(function() {

        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");

      });

    }

    function newready(error, us, random) {

      if (error) throw error;



      var rateById = {};





      random.forEach(function(d) {
        rateById[d.id] = +d.rate;
      });



      svg.append("g")

      .attr("class", "counties")

      .selectAll("path")

      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)

      .enter().append("path")

      .attr("d", path)

      .attr("class", "county")

      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(rateById[d.id]);
      });

      svg.append("path")

      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
        return a.id !== b.id;
      }))

      .attr("class", "states")

      .attr("d", path);

      var tooltip = d3.select("div").append("span")

      .attr("class", "ccc")

      .style("z-index", "10")

      .style("visibility", "hidden")

      .style("position", "absolute")

      .style("text-align", "center")

      .style("width", "60px")

      .style("height", "28px")

      .style("padding", "2px")

      .style("font", "12px sans-serif")

      .style("background", "lightsteelblue")

      .style("border", "0px")

      .style("border-radius", "8px")

      .style("pointer-events", "none")

      .text("here");



      d3.select("div")

      .on("mouseover", function() {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      })

      .on("mousemove", function() {
        return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
      })

      .on("mouseout", function() {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      });



    }



    function Dropdown(val) {

      if (val == "Unemployeement") {

        queue()

        .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")

        .defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv")

        .await(ready);
      } else {

        queue()

        .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")

        .defer(d3.tsv, "random.tsv")

        .await(newready);

      }

    }





    /*

    var text1="Some Bullshit";









    //////// Edited For task 1

    var tooltip = 

       path.append("div")

        .style("z-index", "10")

        .style("visibility", "hidden")

        .style("position", "absolute")   

        .style("text-align","center")     

        .style("width","60px")          

        .style("height", "28px")         

        .style("padding","2px")       

        .style("font","12px sans-serif")    

        .style("background","lightsteelblue") 

        .style("border","0px")    

        .style("border-radius","8px")     

        .style("pointer-events","none") 

        .attr("class", "county")

      .text(text1);



    path



      .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})

      .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})

      .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});  

    ///////

















































    }



    */
  </script>

</body>



</html>)    

        .style("border-radius","8px")     

        .style("pointer-events","none") 

        .attr("class", "county")

      .text(text1);



    path



      .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})

      .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})

      .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});  

    ///////

















































    }



    */
  </script>

</body>



</html>
```

I am not really trained in 3djs.  What I am wondering is if there's a way to merge the two functions ready() and newready().

The intent is to use a stack of files that one page can load.  The dropdown reloads the map using the data from the chosen option.  the option represents the file in the folder.  The current setup inadvertently restricts to just two options because of the split functions.

how do I rectify this?

Comment: The correct refactor for this code is not just "merging" the two functions. There are so many problems in your design (like using an async in the dropdown listener, for starters) that this question would better suit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (specially because you have a **working code** right now). So, I advise that you ask this question over there, with the same tags you're using here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try https://plnkr.co/edit/8Io7rgSjYZSxi5fWTfpA?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
<style>
    .states {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
    }
     .county:hover {
        fill: red !important;
      }
    svg:hover{
    background: black;
    }
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="float:left,width:40%" id="click"></div>
<select onchange="Dropdown(this.value)">
  <option >Unemployeement</option>
  <option >New File</option>
</select>
<script>
    $("div").click(function(){
    alert("here");
    });

    var width = 960,
        height = 500;
    var color = d3.scale.threshold()
        .domain([0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10])
        .range(["#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f"]);

    var path = d3.geo.path();
    var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    queue()
       .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")
        .defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv")
        .await(ready);

    function ready(error, us, unemployment) {
      if (error) throw error;
      var rateById = {};
      unemployment.forEach(function(d) { rateById[d.id] = +d.rate; });
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
          .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "county")
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]);
          });    

      svg.append("path")
          .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a.id !== b.id; }))
          .attr("class", "states")
          .attr("d", path);

     var object=svg.append("foreignobject");
     var div=object.append("div");
     var tooltip=d3.select("div").append("span")
     .attr("class","ccc")
     .style("z-index", "10")

        .style("visibility", "hidden")

        .style("position", "absolute")   

        .style("text-align","center")     

        .style("width","60px")          

        .style("height", "28px")         

        .style("padding","2px")       

        .style("font","12px sans-serif")    

        .style("background","lightsteelblue") 

        .style("border","0px")    

        .style("border-radius","8px")     

        .style("pointer-events","none") 

     .text("here");



    d3.select("div") 
      .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
      .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
      .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});  

     $("span").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
    }

    var dropdownMap = {
      'Unemployeement': 'unemployment.tsv' //Add more file as per need
    }

    function Dropdown(val){
      let file = dropdownMap[val];
      if(!file){
        file = 'random.tsv'
      }
        queue()
        .defer(d3.json,"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")
        .defer(d3.tsv, file)
        .await(ready);
    }
    }

</script>
```

I have used an object that will map dropdown value to its file. 
In future, if you need to add more value then just add dropdown value and 
its file name.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Create a third function that connect both, something like a method (object oriented programming)

on ES6 sintax

```
var func1 = (options) => {
    //do something
}



func1.func2 = (options, data) => {
 //do the same, but a little bit more complex, or complement it

 func1() => {//i'm doing something more}
}
```